# How to pass input params in node js for joining collections?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

My requests collection,

```
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("57e0b8cd5eeba5140b270ca8"), 
  "sent_id" : "57dfcdc21ad7cf658860926d", 
  "recieved_id" : "57dfcddf1ad7cf658860926e", 
  "status" : 1 
}
```

My profile collection

```
 { 
   "_id" : ObjectId("57dfcddf1ad7cf658860926e"), 
   "firstname" : "John", 
   "lastname" : "David", 
   "profilename" : "John David", 
   "email" : "john@gmail.com"
  }
```

Here i want to join the collections with sent_id(collection) = _id(profile) and i tried the below code,

```
exports.getrequestsdetails = function (req, res) {
    var params = req.params;console.log(params)
    var record = db.collection('requests');
    var item = {"sent_id": params.id,"status":1};
  record.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup:
        {
          from: "profile",
          localField: "sent_id",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "profilename"
        }
   }
]).toArray((err, result) => {
   if (err){ return 
    }
      if(result){
            response = {status:'success',data:result};
        } else{
            response = {status:'fail',data:[]};
        }
      res.send(response);
  });

};
```

This is my result where i am not able to see that collections got joined,

```
    {
  "status": "success",
  "data": [
    {
      "_id": "57dfeb279559c37854adb92f",
      "profilename": []
    },
    {
      "_id": "57e0b8cd5eeba5140b270ca8",
      "sent_id": "57dfcdc21ad7cf658860926d",
      "recieved_id": "57dfcddf1ad7cf658860926e",
      "status": 1,
      "profilename": []
    }
  ]
}
```

With the above code i come across 2 problems,

1)I am comparing sent_id and _id ,here the _id is an object type,so how can i compare them.

2)I want to pass the sent id as params and how can i do that?

Can anyone one suggest me help since i am new to node and mongo.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. John's ID is `57dfcddf1ad7cf658860926_e_`, which is NOT equal to the request.sent_id `57dfcdc21ad7cf658860926_d_`. Hence no join.
2. You need to add a `$match` clause to the aggregate() call

   $match: {sent_id: params.id}